# Class method with built-in input function (Python)

Tags: python, class

I have to following exercise:

*Implement a class PersonReader supporting the following methods:*

*input() asks the user for the name and year of birth of a person at shell prompt (using the builtin input function).*

***str** that returns the string "name (year)" (e.g. to be used by the print method when applied to a PersonReader).*

And my idea was to do something like this:

```
class Personreader:

    def __init__(self, name, year): 
        self.name = name
        self.year = year

    def from_input(x): 
        return x(input(),input())

    def __str__(self):
        print(self.name, self.year)
```

However this gives an error when I try and call Personreader.from_input(x) or Personreader.from_input(). How can implement this user input in my class?

Comment: What is the x parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've defined `from_input` as a *regular method*, this means its first parameter is always `self` (no matter what name you give it) and it has to be either called on an instance or provided with an instance.

To make `from_input` an alternative constructor (which seems to be the intent here) you should make it into a *class method* by decorating it with [`@classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod). In that case, the name of the (first) parameter should be `cls` e.g.

```py
    @classmethod
    def from_input(cls):
        return cls(input(), input())
```

Incidentally, your implementation of `__str__` is misguided. `__str__` should *return* a visualisation of the object as a string, it should not *print* it. If you want a printer of some sort, then add a method with that naming e.g. `print_object`. Alternatively, fix your `__str__` then just `print(reader)` or whatever.

Finally, classes are usually CamelCased in python, so it shoud be `PersonReader` not `Personreader`. Though it's unclear what the *reader* part is for, your class is just a person, which can incidentally be defined from inputs (colloquially *readers* are objects which can load data from file or file-like objects e.g. `csv.reader`, so a `PersonReader` would be something which parses a file or file-like object and loads one or more `Person` objects).

Comment: I'm not really sure what a decorator is. Why is necessary that first parameter is cls?

Comment: cls refer class attributes, self refer instance attributes.

Comment: @Jacobiman Method always takes `self` (class instance) as first parameter (thing before the dot that calls method), no matter how you name it. Class method always takes `cls` (class itself) as first parameter (thing before the dot that calls method).

Comment: Basically: `Personreader.from_input()` -> class method `from_input` gets `cls = Personreader`. Thus the `return` value is `Personreader(input(), input())` = calls the normal constructor with 2 values entered by the user.

Comment: @Jacobiman by default Python methods work on *instances*. By prefixing the method definition with `@classmethod` (you can just treat it as magic for now) the method will work on *the class itself* instead. That also changes the first parameter Python provides from the instance (colloquially named `self`) to the class object (colloquially named `cls`). This means you can call `Personreader.from_input()` and it won't complain that it is missing a parameter (which is what it does by default, because it wants to be called on an instance). This also lets you *call* the class object to construct.